# JSON RPC Documentation Tool

Tags: documentation, json-rpc

Are there any Documentation Tools for JSON RPC API's?
I found a lot which are perfect for RESTful API's (Slate, Spotlight, Swagger) but sadly none suitable for JSON RPC API's.

Ideal would be a Tool that can handle both.

Are there any?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found Slate to be ok for the Job - It's Opensource and produces static API Docs.
https://github.com/lord/slate

Answer (score 5):

Found a couple:

- https://github.com/mzernetsch/jrgen
- https://github.com/contributte/anabelle

Looking at using jrgen for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one: https://jsight.io

JSight has HTTP REST and also JSON-RPC 2.0 support, look here for details: https://jsight.io/docs/jsight-api-0-3-quick-tutorial

This is [the JSON-RPC definition example](https://editor.jsight.io/r/qjxRR6a/1) from the site:

```
JSIGHT 0.3

URL /api/rpc
  Protocol json-rpc-2.0

  Method createCat // Create a cat.
    Params
      {
        "cat": @cat
      }
    Result
      {
        "id": 1 // Cat’s id.
      }

  Method getCat // // Get a cat by its id.
    Params
      {
        "id": 1 // Cat’s id.
      }
    Result
      @cat

TYPE @cat
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Tom"
}
```

The same example in the cloud: https://editor.jsight.io/r/qjxRR6a/1